# Selecting a vertex via ancestor vertices

Tags: orientdb

I have the following graph in OrientDB:

V1 <- V2 ... <- Vn

The vertices are class Object and each Object has a property called 'name'.  They are connected with edge of class 'Parent'.

Is there a fast way to select Vn knowing only its ancestor Object.name's using SQL?

I was able to accomplish this in gremlin with the following:

`g.v(#11:0).in('Parent').has('name', 'x').in('Parent').has('name', 'y')`

(repeating the 'in.has' depth times)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

To find 'z' from root node #11:0, with 2 ancestors with names 'x' and 'y':

`SELECT in('Parent')[name = 'x'].in('Parent')[name = 'y'].in('Parent')[name = 'z'] FROM #11:0`

See [here](http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/Document-Field-Part.html)